# Reset password function CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am currently working with CakePHP now if my users forgot their password i wish to allow them to reset it. (i.e me sending a mail to them with their new temp password).

But there is a problem. Passwords stored in my Database are hashed by the Auth component which means that if i try to select all from my User model i will get a hashed version of the password. Futher more i don't know how i will be able to save the password HASHED after generating a new one.

Ive been googling aroung for some time to find an answer to this but couldn't seem to find any examples of how this would be done.

Has anyone tried something similar or know how i can be done?

Comment: Did you find [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/) by googling for the subject?

Comment: I think im missing the problem. Personally I would advise against sending out a temp password as it will defeat the purpose of hashing. But if you must create a temp password generate it, send it, hash it, store it?

Comment: currently i have this in my User model: 

    public function beforeSave($options = array())
    {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        return true;
    }

Does this mean that everything that comes by with the field of password will be hashed?

Comment: I too am against sending temp passwords. I usually generate a key that can be used only once to reset their password. That said, what version of CakePHP are you using? The AuthComponent has changed a fair amount between 1.x and 2.x.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek im using Cake 2.4. And isnt creating a "only work once" password abit more advanced ?

Comment: The standard password-reset feature does not imply fiddling with `AuthComponent` or stored hashes at all; it isn't a one use password at all. It's just another model (call it `PasswordReset` or whatever you want) with two public (non password-protected) views: one to generate, store and send a random code, and another one to perform an actual password change when a valid code is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, 2.x definitely gives more control. I only hash the passwords in my User model's beforeSave method just like you do:

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) { 
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This allows you to create a password in your Controller's password reset action as plain text, email it to the user, and then you set the password in the User model and persist it (password is hashed before it hits the database). The important thing here is that your password stays plain text until your controller calls the save method.

Generally I always add an unset on the password field in controller actions that will save the User record just to make sure it won't get rehashed. A second option would be to add an afterFind callback to your user model that does the unset each time the User model(s) are loaded.

About the one time reset key.... I have an additional field in my User object that I use in two cases. Email verification and password reset. When the user is created it is set to the SHA1( +  + ). A link is emailed to the user that sends them to the User controller's validate action. Once that key is verified, that column gets cleared out in the database.

Same with the password reset. When they request a reset, the value gets generated in the same way and a link to the User controller's reset action gets emailed to the user. They enter their userid and if the key in the link matches the one in their database row, they can change their password. When their password is changed, this value is again cleared.

The biggest issue with sending temporary passwords is that it creates a DoS mechanism (against users, not your site). If I decided to harass someone, I could create a task that keeps resetting their password every hour. They can't get in until they check their email, but then it'll change again. Using a key, they'll get an email with a reset link, but their current password will still work as the presence of a reset code would not keep them from logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot convert encrypt password to decrypt.
So, if you want to read out how you can reset password then read out CakeDC plugin of cakephp.

> https://github.com/CakeDC/users

this is the standard plugin of cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
function admin_reset($token = null) {

        /**
         * if logged in, send to home/dashboard page
         */
        if (count($this->Session->read("Auth.User"))) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }

        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Reset Password');

        $this->layout = 'admin';
        $this->User->recursive = -1;
        if (!empty($token)) {
            $u = $this->User->findBytokenhash($token);
            if ($u) {
                $this->User->id = $u['User']['id'];
                if (!empty($this->data)) {
                    $this->User->data = $this->data;
                    $this->User->data['User']['username'] = $u['User']['username'];
                    $new_hash = sha1($u['User']['username'] . rand(0, 100)); //created token
                    $this->User->data['User']['tokenhash'] = $new_hash;


                    if ($this->User->save($this->User->data, false)) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Password has been updated.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
                        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Token corrupted. Reset link work only for once, please try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            }
        } else {
            //$this->redirect('/');
        }
    }
```